# How can i delete every value row in my SQLite Table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to delete all my values in my sqlite Table.
When I click my button it deletes everything besides the id it keeps counting

so for example:

```
ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
1, Jack Sparrow
2, Johhny Dep
```

if I press delete and add new values, it shows this

```
 ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
    2, Obama Barack
    3, Mike Tyson
```

this is my method

```
 private void DeleteEverything()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from "+NamesContract.NameEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you concerned with the row id? You should never worry about it. Even if it starts from 1962406424 (yes, it may happen).

Comment: Cause it needs to start from 0 when everything is deleted

Comment: No, it really does not need to. Unless you are doing **weird things** with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to drop and recreate the table.
You can find an example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_truncate_table.htm)

Comment: Did you tried db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table" + TABLE_NAME);

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` then SQlite treats this in a specific way. That is **??** (by the looks of it **ID** in your case) is an alias for SQLite's **rowid**.

**rowid** if not specified when inserting a row will automatically be generated and is in general guaranteed to be unique and is normally incremented by one. However, it is not guaranteed to be incremented nor incremented by one.

If you specify `AUTOINCREMENT` (i.e. the latter of the two above) then the guarantee, is that a new **rowid** will be greater but not necessarily by 1.

There is a limit of 9223372036854775807 on the value of **rowid**. If `AUTOINCREMENT` is not used and this limit has been reached then an attempt will made to utilise free numbers (e.g. the rowid of rows that have been deleted). If `AUTOINCREMENT` is specified and the limit has been reached then an insert will fail with an SQLITE_FULL error.

As such, in your case the freed ID's from deleting rows will not be reused.

In short you should never rely upon the **rowid** (or an alias of it) column being a specific value, rather you should rely upon it just being a unique value purely for the purpose of uniquely identifying a row (and perhaps the fastest way of accessing a row).

---

You can, albeit it inadvisable, set **rowid** either by say `INSERT INTO mytable (rowid, myothercolumn) VALUES(1, 'other data')` or if **ID** has been used as an alias then `INSERT INTO mytable (ID, myothercolumn)VALUES(1, 'other data')`.

If you really need the first row to be 1 and then 2 and so on then you could **DROP** the table and then recreate it rather then deleting all rows. e.g. `DROP TABLE mytable`, followed by `CREATE TABLE mytable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT)`. However, I'd suggest you will just end up with issues which will subsequently be far more complicated to determine and correct.

---

*If you think about it, really what does Johnny Depp being **2** signify rather than Barack Obama being **2**? If it is, for example, a popularity rating the surely you'd have some means of determining the popularity and input that directly rather than input it somewhere else to then be used to determine the insertion order and then do the inserts.*

Much of the above is basically a summary of [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

---

As an example of unpredictability, a table was created with:-

`CREATE TABLE mytable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT)`

A row was inserted using `INSERT INTO mytable (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(9223372036854776000,'FRED','BLOGGS')`. Note the use of **9223372036854776000** forces *above the limit* processing.

This was then followed by a number of `INSERT INTO mytable(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES('????','????')` inserts. Note! **without** ID, so using SQLITE's unique identifer determination (*above the limit* processinmg). The resultant table :-

[image]

MARY QUITECONTRARY was the 2nd row inserted,TOM SMITH the 3rd. The two RICHARD BURTON rows are an example of where the unique id could be essential for determining a specific row, both were also inserted without specifying the insertion order.

Note! if the above were tried but with `AUTOINCREMENT` specified, then the second insert, and any subsequent inserts, would fail with an SQLITE_FULL error.